# "Baby is creeping" vs. "baby is crawling" in AmE

Tags: verbs, american-english, word-usage

Years and years ago, I remember reading in a book on AmE usage that the phrasal turn [a baby creeps before it walks](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA198&dq=%22baby+creeps+before%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=9EQ7U_T7Eo3H7AaJg4CoBw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22baby%20creeps%20before%22&f=false) was to some extent more common to AmE than to BrE, which preferred exclusively the ["crawl"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baby+is+creeping%2Cbaby+is+crawling%2Cbaby+creeps%2Cbaby+crawls&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbaby%20is%20crawling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaby%20crawls%3B%2Cc0) version.

And so, I just recently checked on the accuracy of that information on [NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baby+is+creeping%2Cbaby+is+crawling%2Cbaby+creeps%2Cbaby+crawls&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbaby%20is%20creeping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaby%20is%20crawling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaby%20creeps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaby%20crawls%3B%2Cc0), and it actually was fact...[more than a century ago!](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=ArCRwQWotGkC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=%22creeps+before+he+walks%22&source=bl&ots=7fubLl6lQq&sig=zimrZNJaSRW1MrBTt_bveBWwUpE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Cx88U9XZCceA7Qbiv4AY&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22creeps%20before%20he%20walks%22&f=false)

What I would like you to tell is if it would sound sort of weird to hear someone say today in the US that a child "creeps" before walking and running (see [***Synonyms***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crawl)) rather than it crawls.

Also, what's the story to those terms? How did "to crawl" come to prevail and supersede "to creep" to describe the way a baby moves around?

[*As with a plant, so with a child. His mind grows by natural stages. **A child creeps before he walks**, sits before he stands, cries before he laughs, babbles before he talks, draws a circle before he draws a square, lies before he tells the truth, and is selfish before he is altruistic. Such sequences are part of the order of Nature... Every child, therefore, has a unique pattern of growth, but that pattern is a variant of a basic ground plan. (Bigge & Hunt, 1962, p. 166)*](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=wGDsifk6fGoC&pg=PP4&lpg=PP4&dq=%22creeps+before+he+walks%22&source=bl&ots=-ckMmBnsBR&sig=KuLE3zII5gp1sYjZ6XqjsegPrWw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=bjU8U9maHMSm0AXksoDgDw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22creeps%20before%20he%20walks%22&f=false)

My impression is that "to creep" instead of "to crawl" for how a baby moves around might have made a lot of sense in the old days if you consider [the way babies were dressed back then](https://www.flickr.com/photos/roxiejr/3950737294/). Think also of [Swee'Pea's outfit](http://popeye.wikia.com/wiki/Swee%27Pea) in Popeye the Sailorman cartoons.

Besides, [here](http://www.parents.com/baby/development/crawling/baby-creeping-to-crawling/) is a article I just found on Parent.com, which asserts a difference between saying "to creep" and "to crawl."

Comment: Nowadays, you mostly only hear *creep* for things that are creepy (eerie) or at least unexpected. Perhaps the connotations have changed? This is the first I've seen it for a baby's crawl.

Comment: It just occurred to me that *baby creeping* sounds wholly unnatural but *baby creeping along* does not. The connotation is totally different with *along.*

Comment: Both _creep_ and _crawl_ fit quite nicely with [the phonosemantics of the `KR-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kr.pdf).

Comment: I'm British and, though I have visited America many times, and worked with Americans a lot, and have almost reached three score years and ten, I have never heard of a baby 'creeping'. They 'crawl' before they walk.

Comment:      .

Comment: @BraddSzonye But the book I read clearly stated "A baby creeps before it walks." As I said to RyeBread, even though "crawl" is the most common term in modern day AmE in that sense, some US dictionaries support "creep" as the most appropriate alternative.

Comment: Just checked the example in the book, which is prefaced thus: “**Creep** is more often used of quadrupeds or of human beings who move on all fours and proceed slowly, stealthily, or silently.” Also note that this is a reference for discriminating synonyms, **not** a book of common idioms, so the fact they've used babies as an example of creeping doesn't mean that it's a common usage.

Comment: I realize that you're making an effort to vet these questions a little better, but this is another example of a bizarre usage that only barely stands up to a sniff test (in that Google Ngrams potentially shows a substantial use over a century ago). Please see [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) and try to do a better job of evaluating which questions are at least plausible.

Comment: I hope it helps. The better you do at rubber duck problem solving, the more likely people are to welcome your questions at Stack Exchange, rather than down-voting them. And you may find that you no longer even need to ask some questions (or you can post your own answer along with the question, if you think it would be interesting to other people).

Comment: "Creeping" is also American slang for partaking in certain activities without the consent of your significant other.

Comment: Can anybody explain the downvotes here? Relative noob to this stack.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald Thank you for pointing out, Preston! :-)

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald - not only the downvotes on the question but the upvotes that support the usage of creep to describe baby movements.  Once a week I answer what I think is a very simple question and it gets voted on the opposite (obviously by nonAE speakers).... whatever.

Comment: @JohnLawler John: Do you have any idea why "creep" fell gradually into disuse in behalf of "crawl" to describe the way a toddler moves along? Both Random House and Merriam-Webster seem to support "creep" as the appropriate term in that sense.

Comment: @tchrist Tchrist: would you consider the "meaning to" in "it should be borne in mind that there are many other meanings to these words" grammatical or ungrammatical?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet: No idea at all. Though there are two caveant: (1) don't confuse dictionary meanings or Google hits for real language; they only cover the written language. (2) to answer that question accurately would take a sociolinguistic survey, which is expensive and unlikely to be performed; so we'll never know whether it **has** declined in speech, nor what factors were involved.

Comment: @tchrist If you check on my first OPs, you'll notice that I started on ELU using "the sense/meaning of", but at some point switched to "the sense/meaning to" after coming across such usage scattered here and there, which I thought -- erroneously -- as more idiomatic to English. I'm afraid it is not a dictionary thing this time.

Comment: @JohnLawler Clothing fashion for babies might be one of the factors in why it declined, in writing at least.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Arg you shouldn't use **caveant* around me, you know it short-circuits my brains, all of them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NG, as an Ame speaker who has (as a doctor) delivered ~100 babies then taken care of them as they grew up, needing to know the stages of development and milestones, and needing to discuss them with (usually mom), I think I can attest with some authority to which one is common in my part of the US.

A baby *crawls* before it *cruises* (walks by holding on to things) before it *toddles* (takes a few unsteady steps and falls - where we get our word toddler from) before it *walks*. (We used the [Denver Development Milestones Test](http://drhart.net/clinic/forms/Denver%20II%20Developmental%20Milestones.pdf), or DDII, to keep track of progress.)

Having said all that, I'm aware of *creeps* (alone or with along/across) and do not find it odd. In general, though, things that creep along the floor are doing so stealthily (the cat crept up on/to the bird and sprang), or horrifyingly (*the severed hand crept across the floor*) - generally. We even have a name for this for kids: [creepy-crawly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/creepy-crawly). In addition, I had a toy when I was young called Creepy Crawlers, which allowed me to make/bake plastic bugs, and, as I was a good mon, my kids did as well. (To see how this worked, visit [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHr6irnvd8I).)

Fun question!

Comment: I find some of these terms to be dated... just saying.  It is AE but not modern.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Of course it’s modern.  Do you think your interlocutrix a time traveller?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd The funny thing to it is I just found that MW's Dictionary of Synonyms, Ed. 1984, validates "to creep" as the most frequent option to refer to quadruplets or humans who move on all fours, and proceed slowly, stealthily, or silently. If indeed "crawl" is more common than "creep" in modern day AmE, some authoritative sources apparently state "creep" as an appropriate alternative in that sense. http://books.google.com.br/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA198&dq=%22baby+creeps+before%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=aVE7U5yILKSU7QbFroDoDQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22baby%20creeps%20before%22&f=false

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Despite their strange example of babies creeping, you should take that definition to heart, **especially** the part about crawling stealthily. That's what makes it creepy. Not all crawling is creeping.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet - I am not sure where medica is from but no one from around my region would ever describe their baby as creeping unless they baby was being creepy or they were making a joke.  And like I said in my answer - if you use it to describe another person's baby, that is not a good thing.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet "Crawls" is far more common than "creeps" on East Coast US.

Comment: @outisnihil Sure. I can't seem to find any fault in that. What I wish someone could tell is how "crawl" came to prevail and supersede "creep" in AmE usage. In addition, if you check my sources, "creep" seems to have more accuracy than "crawl" to describe the way a baby moves along.

Answer (score -1):

As a dad to two recent crawlers in the US I can say that they crawled, but I never saw a creep.

If a parent said to me "My little 7-month-old was creeping along."  I would seriously have no clue what that baby was doing.  I might guess they were in a baby walker and moving around slowly.  I have never heard it used as a synonym for crawling.

There is also the term military-crawl when babies scoot along on their tummies using their knees and feet to push them forward inch by inch.  When they are crawling we tend to think it is just hands and knees (and down) hitting the ground.

[Baby movements](http://www.yourparenting.co.za/baby/development/physical/stages-of-babys-mobility) in usual order (one of my kids crawled after walking):

- roll
- squirm
- tummy time
- military crawl
- crawl
- cruise - might also say wobble
- walk

I am not saying that creep was never used or could not be used by an older generation but none of my friends with kids would appreciate me saying their kid was "creeping".