# Is there an unambiguous word to mean "moving slowly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Besides "crawling", is there another verb to describe slow movement?

It would be best if the word is not a homograph (has no other meanings besides "move slowly").

Comment: [yes](http://thesaurus.com/browse/crawl)

Comment: yes yes yes yes - *creeping, inching, edging, dawdling,* etc.

Comment: Answering your first rather than second question: **tardigrade**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider "[creep](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/creep)."

> **creep**: to move or proceed very slowly.

E.g.

*Traffic creeps at that hour.*

Comment: *creep* seems to also have meaning of "surreptitious" / "sneaky" etc...

Comment: @Pacerier Correct. Check out my question "A baby creeps before it walks." :-)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think *creep* is a suitable word here for the same reason provided by http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161094/baby-is-creeping-vs-baby-is-crawling-in-ame#comment-336308

Comment: @Pacerier "creep" is the best fit here. Check out online dictionaries for its definition. If you don't like it still and all, then consider "plod" [to move one's way or walk along (a path, road, etc.) with heavy, usually slow steps].

Answer (score 1):

- Glacial
- Snail
- Sloth
- Creep
- Drag

Comment: Btw, is "glacial" and "sloth" able to be used as a *verb*?

Comment: @Pacerier Also, is `snail`?